# Facebook iOS Logout dialog

Tags: ios, facebook, logout

I'm using the official Facebook SDK and I'm struggling to logout the user.
The Action sheet (Logout dialog) appears with two buttons Log Out and Cancel but clicking on the Logout doesn't do anything. Do I need to implement another interface other than FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate?

Comment: The answer to this question is using a custom logout button and what I want is to use the Logout dialog of the Facebook SDK